# IntelliJ how to change color in output window

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is there any way to get rid of the blue highlighting or better yet get rid of that line all together.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the highlighting, go to Editor | Colors & Fonts | Console Colors and change the color for "System output".

The background color is the color of the folded text (Colors & Fonts | General | Folded text).

Getting rid of the line is not possible.

Comment: this does change the text but the highlight is still there.